Ni-Fi Import Template is not showing
I have Ni-Fi 2.0 M4 system installed in my local system. But From my local system, I couldnt able to import the template from another Ni-Fi Server. The image attached for your reference. Is there any option to upload the existing template to the local server.
Please let me know how to upload the existing template into current Ni-Fi server.

The former XML-based "templates" have been deprecated and are completely removed as of Apache NiFi 2.x releases.
Instead of templates you can use the JSON-based flow definitions, which can be downloaded and uploaded from and to NiFi more easily. Just right-click on a ProcessGroup and select "Download flow definition".
Look for "Download flow definition" in the "User Guide" in the documentation for more information.
